# Workaround limitation of Multiple Inheritance Need

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I have 3 classes, each of the classes can be inherited individually for certain inheritied abilities.

But 2 of the classes can be inherited into the 3rd to create a "super" class that includes the abilities of the other 2 and their default logic implementation.

What is the best approach for this to keep coding logic centralized?

As you will see below, `Class2` is a distilled form of what i have built in `Class3`.  I want to implement the validation logic for the properties in one location, instead of developing an interface and having to implement the logic over and over again for every implement.

There is a situation where `Class2` can be used by itself as well as being coupled with `Class1`.  Each of the classes have their own unique use but `Class3` combines `2` & `1` for a ultimate implementation combining both classes functionality.

Classes:

```
public mustinherit class Class1(of T as {New, Component})
  private _prop as T

  public sub New()
    ...
  end sub

  protected friend readonly property Prop1 as T
    Get
      ..validation..
      return me._prop
    end get
  end property
end class

public mustinherit class Class2
  private _prop as short

  public sub new(val as short)
    me._prop = val
  end sub

  protected friend readonly property Prop2 as short
    get
      return me._prop
    end get
  end property
end class
```

Current Class3 implementation:

```
public mustinherit class Class3(of T as {New, Component})
  Inherits Class1(of T)

  'Distilled the logic design below into its own MustInherit class cause this design
  '  by itself is useful without Clas1 implementation.
  private _prop as Short  <--- Same as Class2._prop

  public sub New(val as short)
    me._prop = val
  end sub

  protected friend readonly property Prop2 as short
    get
      return me._prop
    end get
  end property
end class
```

#### Per @Servy:

Class1

```
public mustinherit class Data(of T as {New, Component})
...
end class
```

Class2

```
public mustinherit class Brand
...
end class
```

Class3

```
public mustinherit class BrandData(of T as {New, Component})
  inherits Data(Of T)
...
end class
```

Comment: Didnt think you could implement inner logic to properties, subs, or functions in a Interface.

Comment: Everytime I found myself wanting to do "multiple inheritance", I quickly realized my object model was rather wrong and needed a serious rethink.

Comment: Rather than just stating `Class1`, `Class3`, etc. why not describe what they *really* represent, as that may help provide a more suitable implementation.  For the record though, anytime you would want multiple inheritance you can just use interfaces combined with composition of the objects you would otherwise inherit.

Comment: Again, each of these classes can be inherited individually, except `Class3` could benefit from `Inherit/Implement` of the other 2 classes so i dont have to recode the logic i already designed.  As well, any logic change in `Class1` and `Class2` will carry over to `Class3`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to implement the validation logic for the properties in one
>   location, instead of developing an interface and having to implement
>   the logic over and over again for every implement.

No need to implement interface over and over again. You must implement you validation logic at once then inject it to your classes which needs validation.

```
interface IValidationLogic
{}

class Class1
{
    protected readonly IValidationLogic _validationLogic;
    public Class1(IValidationLogicvalidationLogic)
    {
        _validationLogic = validationLogic;
    }
}

class Class2
{
    protected readonly IValidationLogic _validationLogic;
    public Class2(IValidationLogicvalidationLogic)
    {
        _validationLogic = validationLogic;
    }
}

class Class3 : Class2
{
    public Class2(IValidationLogicvalidationLogic)
         : base(validationLogic) 
    {}
}


class MyValidationLogic : IValidationLogic
{}


var obj = new Class3(new MyValidationLogic())
```

Comment: So because `Class2`/`Brand` could be viewed as a Data-Type, i should create an internal variable and implement the Property over and over again?  Seems kind of duplicative to always have to implement the property (thru implicit or explicit) every time to expose the property to the instantiation.

Comment: Its not a direct solution but there is the are ongoign debates over Inheritance vs Composition. if you search on google for Composition vs Inheritance it will discuss the differences. There are many threads here on stack-exchange on the subject this

Comment: "i should create an internal variable and implement the Property over and over again?" What you mean? Are you about `_validationLogic`?